# workspace is missing folders of the local repository after pulling

Tags: github

I have a local repository with several folders and a project that is connected to that local repository. However, when I pull (right click, team, pull)
my project on the workspace is not properly updated, because it has only one of the folders of the local repository, not all of them?
How can I get all the contents of the local repository to my project in the workspace?
the corresponding github page is
https://github.com/Sonicvi/RocketProject

in the attached screenshots you can see my local repository and my project tree. The project is missing the folders of the local repositoy even after pulling the latest changes.
I dont understand. Can you help me?
​Thank you for help

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you commit and push from your local repository?

Comment: yes, but now I need it the other way around. remote rep->  local rep -> project in workspace